# Разрешено ли присваивание переменных-массивов в Оберон-07?

Tags: oberon, oberon-07

Разрешена ли операция присвоения массивов в Обероне-07 (с их копированием) ? Или допускаются только указатели на массивы? Или зависит от реализации? В трансляторе OberonJS вроде как поддерживается, а из описания языка вроде нет. Или в других версиях Оберона такая операция может поддерживаться?

```
...
VAR
    arr1, arr2 : ARRAY 5 OF INTEGER;
...
arr2 := arr1;  (*разрешена ли эта операция?*)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, присваивание массивов в Обероне-07 разрешено.

Операция `arr2 := arr1` разрешена.

См. [сообщение о языке Оберон-07](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/wirth/Oberon/Oberon07.Report.pdf) ([перевод на русский](https://modela.online/oberon)), раздел 9.1. Присваивания:

> Тип выражения должен быть таким же, как у обозначений. Имеют место следующие исключения:
>
> 1. Константу NIL можно присвоить переменным любого типа указателя или процедуры.
> 2. Строки могут быть присвоены любому массиву символов, если количество символов в строке меньше, чем количество символов в массиве. (Добавляется нулевой символ). Односимвольные строки также могут быть присвоены переменным типа CHAR.
> 3. В случае записей тип источника должен быть расширением типа адресата.
> 4. Открытый массив может быть присвоен массиву равного базового типа.

Возможно, Вас ввело в заблуждение предложение, написанное перед указанным фрагментом:

> Если значение параметра структурировано (имеет тип массив или запись), никакого присваивания ему или его элементам не допускаются. Для импортированных переменных также не допускаются присваивания.

Здесь говорится не об обычных переменных, а именно о параметрах. В Обероне-07 все параметры-массивы и параметры-записи передаются по ссылке в режиме «только для чтения». Если же при объявлении процедуры перед параметром указать слово VAR, то этот параметр будет передаваться с возможностью изменения (но также по ссылке).

Answer (score 0):

В-сущности, в репорте не сказано об этом ничего. Но следуя принципу наименьшего удивления (с учётом того, что здесь не POINTER TO ARRAY) -- должно быть копирование. В случае POINTER -- должно происходить присвоение указателя.
Но ещё раз повторю: в репорте этот момент не раскрывается. В OberonJS, имхо -- этот момент реализован правильно.